# "lossless" float to BYTE conversion

Tags: c++, c, math, casting

I'm using libnoise to generate Perlin noise on a 1024x1024 terrain grid. I want to convert its float output to a BYTE between 0 and 255. The question is ultimately a math one: **how can I convert a value in the real interval (-1,1) to the integer one (0,255) minimizing loss?**

Comment: You don't really have to be all that careful about "minimizing loss" here. A float can easily represent an integer in the range (0, 255). (If you were talking about a much larger range, requiring more significant bits, then your concern might be warranted.)

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves, if your math is sloppy it is extremely easy to have a solution where 0 or 255 are under-represented in the output. That's how I read the requirement to "minimize loss".

Comment: @MarkRansom That's true. I was interpreting "minimize loss" as general "floats are unreliable" hysteria. It seems like most programmers go through three stages when using floats: unaware that precision problems exist (ie: "floats are just Real numbers, right?"), hysterical/ultra-paranoid that floats are going to mangle data in unpredictable ways, and (finally) aware that precision problems exist but also aware that they're deterministic. Maybe the "omg" in omgzor's userid is why I assumed the hysteria interpretation... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This formula will give you a number in [0, 255] if your input range excludes the endpoints:

```
(int)((x + 1.0) * (256.0 / 2.0))
```

If you are including the endpoints (and then it usually written [-1,1] rather than (-1,1)) you will need a special case for `x == 1.0` to round that down to 255.

Comment: If the interval includes 1.0 there's a very slight possibility of overflow. I'd use 255.99999 to be safe.

Comment: Thanks, I'm excluding the endpoints, the notation (-1,1) was intentional.

Comment: @omgzor, I thought it might be, but then you used the notation (0,255) for the output. 255.99999 works for both cases, 256.0 for only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The best way might depend on the distribution of floats in (-1,1); if in some areas there are more of them and in some there are less, you might want to increase the "precision" in the former at the expense of the latter. Basically, if you have a probability function for the output defined at this interval, you may split (0,1) - the interval of probability values - to 256 equal sub-intervals, and for each given float you calculate into which sub-interval its probability function value falls. For noise the probability function is (or at least should be) close to linear, so perhaps the answer of Mark Byers is the way to go.